# Technique to force constructor calls to be easily searchable

Tags: c++, named-constructor

I would like to write a constructor in a way that finding all usages is easy to do with global file search

An attempt at doing this is below but it is inadequate:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Example {
    enum class ECtor { eCtor };
    explicit Example(ECtor) { std::cout << "Ctor" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    // Intended requirement: constructor calls can be searched for by searching
    // for "ECtor"
    Example good(Example::ECtor::eCtor);

    // Problem: This compiles which ruins the intention
    Example bad({});

    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately `{}` can be used as an argument despite the constructor being `explicit` meaning searching for "ECtor" will not find the usage

The argument could be made that searching for `Example` could be done instead but in a large framework that can be very time consuming due to inheritance and containers

I am aware of the named constructor idiom but that also comes with issues. For example, it may be the case that a class can be instantiated with `new` in some places, with custom `new` calls in other places, on the heap in other places, etc. Each would require its own named method so I'd rather avoid that approach

Comment: Use a better naming convention.  Use an IDE that can present you the location of the declaration or definition of a class.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews What naming convention can you imagine that would solve the issue?

Comment: How many elements are in `ECtor`? If only a few, you could consider using tag types instead, that would prevent `{}` as argument to constructor.

Comment: Some famous companies start class names with 'C'.  One company started their classes with 'T'.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen `ECtor` serves no purpose other than to add an argument to the constructor that can be searched

Comment: @ThomasMatthews What would stating the class with 'C' or 'T' do in regard to searching for the constructor usages more easily?

Comment: You could search for `"Example(` depending on your coding convention, or use a regular expression search.  One of the entries should be the constructor.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Searching for "Example(" could easily miss "Example (", or "Example {", or any constructor calls done with containers of `Example`. It isn't helpful. Another example, `myVec.emplace_back()` doesn't even have "Example" in it but is a constructor call

Comment: If I search the shop code for `Flash`, I will get a lot of hits.  If I search for `CFlash`, there will be fewer false positive hits.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews None of your suggestions are helpful and is making the comment section long

Comment: I was going to propose tag types, but then I realised they suffer from the same issue. You can always provide an alias to any name, be it a type name or variable name, so one can always work around whatever clever way of forcing use of one name you can think of. Better stick with `explicit` and write a regex or get a good IDE with "Find Usages" functionality.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen If you can imagine a solution that prevents `{}` from being a constructor call that would be adequate for me. At least I would find any `typedef` and `using` of `ECtor` while I search for it (I wouldn't want any of those in the framework anyway)

Comment: Here's what I was working on: https://godbolt.org/z/rzco1b5Tx. Probably the same can be done with enum instead of type, as long as you provide second deleted constructor to create ambiguity if `{}` is used.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Your ambiguity idea is a good one, I will play around with it

Comment: Add `= delete` at the end of the constructor declaration and compile if you really want to be sure to find then all. Or make the constructor private could also works in many cases or the deprecated attribute. I would not recommand to add extra parameter only for easier search as it make the code less readable, prevent default construction and might add some run-time overhead.

Comment: You could use `clang`, dump and parse its AST: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/IntroductionToTheClangAST.html

Comment: Why is ability to find usage that critical, just out of curiosity? Been writing c++ for over a decade professionally and ability to find the usage of a method/ctor in a code base has never ever appeared as a criteria that affected design or implementation in any way.

Comment: To search for all constructor calls I'd probably use something like `clang-query`.

Comment: @cplusplusrat I am whittling down a large framework someone else wrote to a much more basic one. I don't want to change its existing desirable behavior and some constructors have a lot of side effects when they are called. I need to find all those cases and organize them in a better way. I also need to find them multiple times because I whittle down in steps so triggering a zillion compiler errors (like deleting a constructor) is more annoying then having an easy way to search for them

Comment: @asimes A simpler way would be to just comment out the ctor whose usage you want to track down in your class and look at all the compiler errors. But looks like you found something that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible approach is to define a deleted constructor which receives an initializer list. In this way, {} is interpreted as an initializer list instead of an enum.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

struct Example {
    enum class ECtor { eCtor };
    explicit Example(ECtor) { std::cout << "Ctor" << std::endl; }
    explicit Example(std::initializer_list<double>) = delete;
};

int main() {
    // Intended requirement: constructor calls can be searched for by searching
    // for "ECtor"
    Example good(Example::ECtor::eCtor);

    // This don't compile anymore
    Example bad({});

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why use `std::initializer_list<double>`?

Comment: Because, when using braces, `initializer_list` takes preference over other uses of the braces.Then, if the constructor with `initializer_list` is deleted, the objects cannot be created using empty braces

Comment: Let me clarify, why `double`?

Comment: It can use any type (not only double) and it will work.

Comment: I'll go with `std::initializer_list<ECtor>`